# Renaming custom control in VS 2010, receiving err: "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a customized Windows Forms control by following these MSDN instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z.aspx

(Article title: How to: Inherit from Existing Windows Forms Controls; the instructions are for Visual Studio 2010)

These instructions do seem to work, but if I change the name of the control from CustomControl1 to any other name (by changing the class name and constructor name), I receive the message:

"The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"

I've looked at the similar questions and answers here, and I don't think any of them answer this, but I could be wrong.  If I am, then I didn't understand the answer.

I hope someone can help me on this.  I've wasted a lot of time on it already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes after posting this question, I figured out the answer.  I imagine that for someone with even moderate experience with Visual Studio, the answer is obvious, but it wasn't for me, so maybe I can save somebody some time if they happen to read this.

To rename a newly created custom control which has been created by following the MSDN instructions in the link provided in the question:

- Rename the generated source file from CustomControl1.cs (for C#) to the desired name
- Say yes when Visual Studio asks you if you want to change all the references

That's it.  The custom control name is changed, and no more error.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the class name you'll notice that a red line appears under the end of the new class name.

Hover over it until a little box appears, then click on that box, and then click on "Rename...". (A shortcut to it is: `Ctrl+.` <-that's the period key.)

That's all.

The reason for the error is that the `InitializeComponent` method is in a separate file with the old class name. By choosing the "Rename..." as mentioned above - Visual Studio will rename the class in that file as well. It also changes the constructor's name.